# How to dynamically create textboxes with adding css and how to get value dynamically in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, placeholder

I created some dynamically textboxes on asp.net

```
for (int a = 1; a <= int.Parse(ddl.SelectedItem.Text); a++)
{
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.ID = "txtMonth" + a;          
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);
}
```

but it looks like this:

[image]

but I want to look this type:

[image]

and also another question how can I get each textbox value?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Simply add a `Label` with inner HTML set to `<br />` after each of the Text boxs.

Values can be found in the `Request` collection.